# How can I solve the modelMapper error of DTO?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I was using modelMapper and there was a problem that DTO was not mapping.

```
ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping domain.Order to domain.dto.order.OrderResponseInfo

1 error
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping domain.Order to dto.order.OrderResponseInfo

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:374)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:69)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:497)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:340)
    at net.class101.homework.service.OrderService.orders(OrderService.java:74)
```

**OrderService**

```java
    @Transactional  // it's okay
    public OrderResponseInfo order(OrderRequestInfo dto) {

        Product product = productRepository.findOneByNaturalKey(dto.getProduct().getNaturalKey())
                .orElseThrow(NotExistProductException::new);

        OrderProduct orderProduct = OrderProduct.createOrderProduct(product, product.getPrice(), dto.getCount());

        Order order = Order.createOrder(orderProduct);
        orderRepository.save(order);

        return modelMapper.map(order, OrderResponseInfo.class);
    }

    @Transactional // it's modelMapperError
    public OrderResponseInfo orders(List<OrderRequestInfo> orderRequests) {

        List<OrderProduct> orderProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        for(OrderRequestInfo order : orderRequests){
            orderProducts.add(OrderProduct.createOrderProduct(order.getProduct(), order.getOrderPrice(), order.getCount()));
        }

        Order order = Order.createOrder(orderProducts.toArray(new OrderProduct[0]));
        orderRepository.save(order);

        return modelMapper.map(order, OrderResponseInfo.class);
    }
```

**DTO**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderResponseInfo {

    private Long id;
    private Order order;
    private BigDecimal totalOrderPrice;
    private BigDecimal shippingCharge;
    private BigDecimal requirePaymentPrice;
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;

    public OrderResponseInfo(Long id, Order order) {
        this.id = id;
        this.order = order;
        this.totalOrderPrice = order.getTotalPrice();
        this.shippingCharge = order.getShippingCharge();
        this.requirePaymentPrice = order.getRequirePaymentPrice();
        this.orderProducts = order.getOrderProducts();
    }
}
```

`Order` and `OrderProduct` have a 'OneToMany' relationship and we thought that a single order could have multiple `OrderProducts`.

When i tested one order now, modelMapper worked normally.

However, there was an error in modelMapper's handling of several orders, but I am not sure why.

The only difference between a single order(`OrderService.order()`) and a number of orders(`OrderService.orders()`) is the difference between the factors and the production of `OrderProduct` through the for loop.

**Edited**

Instead of `return modelMapper.map (order, orderResponseInfo.class);`, `return new OrderResponseInfo(order.getId(), order);` was used to confirm that the mapping works properly.

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you show us the models? and what MatchingStrategies are you using ?

Comment: @Aman I added what you said, and I added the code that I am temporarily using after 'Edit'.

Comment: the models, I meant by both `order` and `OrderResponseInfo`. But, you said that `Order` has `OrderProduct`, why `List<OrderProduct> orderProducts` in `OrderResponseInfo`?